# Mysql insert from stored procedure gives error 1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

For some strange reason, inserting from stored procedure is not working. 
This is what Im trying to do:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  test(
id                                          INT(9)                  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,name                                       VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL 
,PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    insert into test (name) values('A');

Inserting from command line works with no problems.

Then I created a stored procedure to do the same kind of insert:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS storedtest;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE storedtest()
    BEGIN
        declare insert_sql varchar(200);
        SET insert_sql = 'insert into test (name) values(3)';
        SELECT insert_sql;
        PREPARE mystm FROM @insert_sql;
        EXECUTE mystm;
   END$$
DELIMITER ;

call storedtest();
```

This gives me the error:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

NULL? Where did NULL came from?

I also tried changing the sql-insert to look like this (dont know if it is a good way):

```
    SET insert_sql = "insert into test (name) values('3')";
```

But mysql gives me exactly the same error.
Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NULL` MySQL is reporting is an empty user variable `@insert_sql`, which is different from the local stored procedure local variable `insert_sql` which you allocated with `DECLARE`.

MySQL's `DECLARE` is used for variables local to a stored program, [but according to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html), `PREPARE stmt FROM ...` expects either a string literal or a *user variable*, which are the type preceded with `@`.

> PREPARE **stmt_name** FROM **preparable_stmt**
>
> **preparable_stmt** is either a string literal or a user variable that contains the text of the SQL statement.

You can allocate the untyped user variable with `SET` so there is no need for `DECLARE`.  You may wish to set it to `NULL` when you're finished.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS storedtest;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE storedtest()
BEGIN
  -- Just SET the user variable
  SET @insert_sql = 'insert into test (name) VALUES (3)';
  SELECT @insert_sql;

  -- Prepare & execute
  PREPARE mystm FROM @insert_sql;
  EXECUTE mystm;
  
  -- Deallocate the statement and set the var to NULL
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE mystm;
  SET @insert_sql = NULL;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```